# How can i insert the inline_keyboard with php ? my code not insert the keyboard with msg

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, sendmessage

```
$txt = $data;
if ($telegram == "on"){
    $keyboard = json_encode([
        "inline_keyboard" => [
            [
                [
                    "text" => "Button 1",
                    "callback_data" => "1"
                ],
                [
                    "text" => "Button 2",
                    "callback_data" => "2"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $send = ['chat_id'=>$chat_id,'text'=>$txt];
    $website_telegram = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$bot_url}&reply_markup={$keyboard}";
    $ch = curl_init($website_telegram . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($send));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

my code not insert the keyboard with msg, on my but display just the message without keyboard

Comment: Welcome! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: The `/sendMessage` is going to be in the `reply_markup` parameter. Is that correct?

Comment: You're making a POST request, but are setting GET parameters. You should likely move `reply_markup` to the request body instead.

Comment: @Sammitch where i put the variable $keyboard ?